# How I can show an attribute as a two dimensional array(matrix) in UML?

Tags: uml, object-oriented-analysis

I am doing the UML of my system and I have an attribute `boardGame` that is a matrix (`array[6][6]`).
What is the correct way to show it in the UML? I tried this:

```
 Game
-boardGame: array[][]
```

but the program I am using to do it (SatarUML) does not accept it in that way.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can show it like this (assuming it's untyped like in your example):

[image]

(note that the square bracket pairs `[]` are rendered with a sub-optimal font from the UML tool)

If it's typed use this format:

[image]

where you need to replace `type` by the one you are actually using.